# Windows 10 showing error on installation

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I was going to install Windows 10 version 1511 using the iso which i downloaded directly from the windows's website. But after the windows installer completed copying files and started the install it suddenly showed an error saying:

> Windows cannot install required files. The file may be corrupt or missing. Make sure all files required for installation are available, and restart the installation. Error code: 0x80070570

I also tried reinstalling several times and deleted the folder which was created during copying the setup files but it didn't worked out. 
What to do now ?

Comment: "Which i downloaded directly from the windows's website." - Where exactly, what version (x86,x64, or the combined version), and have you tried downloading it again?

Comment: i downloaded the 64-bit version , and no i haven't tried to download it again, because I'm low on data right now.

Answer (score 1):

Either the ISO you downloaded is corrupt or whatever media you put the ISO on is now corrupt. If you burned the ISO to a CD/DVD then you may just need to burn it again to a new disc. If the ISO itself is corrupt, you would need to download it again.

Comment: Isn't there any other solution to this ?

Comment: @Harsiddh - You determine if the .ISO is corrupt.  You can also just download the .ISO again.

Comment: Okay ! So that's the last choice left for me. I'll try that . Thanks

Comment: @Harsiddh That's exactly what I said originally...